# How can get datetime not insert to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have some data like this.

```
with WorkingTime as(
    select 1 Userid, '2019-04-03' RegDay, '08:48' CheckIn, '18:00' CheckOut union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-05' , '08:00' , '18:00'  union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-06' , '07:48' , '18:00'  union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-09' , '08:20' , '18:00'  
)
```

Now I want to count DateOff of UserId 1.

```
select Userid
     ,sum(case when CheckIn < '08:00' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLate
     ,'?' as TotalDateOff 
from WorkingTime 
where RegDay between '2019-04-03' and '2019-04-11'
group by Userid
```

The dateoff from  '2019-04-03' to '2019-04-11' is '2019-04-04','2019-04-07','2019-04-10','2019-04-11'. This mean column TotalDateOff is 4. How can I achieve like this?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server or Postgres? Those are two very different DBMS products

Comment: I have 1 project but publish for 2 DB: Microsoft SQL Server and Postgres. I think It can be the same solution

Comment: Your last line that is your requirement is not clear. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You can see from '2019-04-03' to '2019-04-11', we have 4 day off. But how can calculater it?

Comment: Is a checkin **before** 08:00 really considered "late". Shouldn't that condition be `checkin > '08:00'`?

Comment: count() will work

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use CTE to get a list of dates (from - to), which will be incremental by day or month or whatever incremental method required.

You could use it in your current CTE by adding it to current one which will get the minimum date and increment by 1 day until it hits max date. Then, all you need is a simple left join, which will join the dates, if the date is not existed in the WorkingTime it'll be NULL value. Then, all you need to to is just count those nulls to get the total dateoff.

Example :

```
;with WorkingTime as(
    select 1 Userid, '2019-04-03' RegDay, '08:48' CheckIn, '18:00' CheckOut union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-05' , '08:00' , '18:00'  union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-06' , '07:48' , '18:00'  union all
    select 1 , '2019-04-09' , '08:20' , '18:00'  
) , WorkingOff AS (
    SELECT Userid, CAST(MIN(RegDay) AS DATE) MinRegDay
    FROM WorkingTime
    GROUP BY Userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Userid,  DATEADD(DAY, 1, MinRegDay)
    FROM WorkingOff
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, MinRegDay) < '2019-04-11'
) 
SELECT 
    wf.Userid
,   SUM(CASE WHEN wt.CheckIn < '08:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalLate
,   SUM(CASE WHEN wt.RegDay IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalDateOff 
FROM WorkingOff wf
LEFT JOIN WorkingTime wt ON wf.MinRegDay = wt.RegDay AND wf.Userid = wt.Userid
where wf.MinRegDay between '2019-04-03' and '2019-04-11'
GROUP BY wf.Userid
```

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres this can be done using `generate_series()` to generate the list of dates for each userid and the use that in a left join:

```
with workingtime (userid, regday, checkin, checkout) as(
  values
    (1, date '2019-04-03', '08:48'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (1, date '2019-04-05', '08:00'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (1, date '2019-04-06', '07:48'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (1, date '2019-04-09', '08:20'::time, '18:00'::time),  
    (1, date '2019-04-10', '08:00'::time, '18:00'::time),

    (2, date '2019-04-03', '08:48'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (2, date '2019-04-06', '07:00'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (2, date '2019-04-08', '07:48'::time, '18:00'::time),
    (2, date '2019-04-09', '08:20'::time, '18:00'::time)
), ranges as (
   select w.userid, dt.day::date as regdate
   from (
     select distinct userid
     from workingtime
   ) w
     cross join generate_series(date '2019-04-03', date '2019-04-11', interval '1 day') as dt(day)
)
select r.userid,  
       count(*) filter (where checkin < '08:00') as total_late,
       count(*) filter (where wt.regday is null) as total_days_off
from ranges r
  left join workingtime wt on wt.userid = r.userid and wt.regday = r.regdate
group by r.userid
order by r.userid;
```

The above returns:

```
userid | total_late | total_days_off
-------+------------+---------------
     1 |          1 |              4
     2 |          2 |              5
```

Answer (score 0):

To add data you need a data source.  In this case you need a source that has all possible dates.  This is a common problem that takes several forms - in your case you should create a table for all dates and then you are trying to find what is there and not here.  For example a calendar table.

Other uses for such a table is to define fiscal year, fiscal quarter, maybe holidays, etc.

You can also create such a [source] through a function you can call in from clause - but best and simplest option is probably to have table.  You can generate it for a 1000 years and be done!